# Social media manager tools are unable to add post to my facebook page

Tags: facebook-pages

I have been using a SMM tool to schedule my posts to my facebook page (and other social media channels) for that matter. It was working fine and the posts were added to the FB page. However, recently it stopped showing the posts on the FB page while all other channels show the posts.

There is no error at SMM tool side. Also, the images attached to the scheduled posts are being added to the Timeline Photos, but the posts are not being created under Posts tab and do not show up under Activity Log!

Please see these two screenshots.

1. Posts added from SMM tool: https://www.screencast.com/users/shahzaad/folders/Default/media/77636c4d-7c4d-4494-acfb-1e0de0710db0
2. No  SMM tool created post showing up under the Posts tab only manual ones are showing up https://content.screencast.com/users/shahzaad/folders/Default/media/bd55b339-abeb-4e88-b318-c525ba6f6403/LWR_Recording.png
3. But the images of those automated posts are showing up under Timeline Photos

https://www.screencast.com/users/shahzaad/folders/Default/media/b19827b9-3436-4e19-b492-6f0b01fc592b

I tried with another social media tool as well, but the same result. So it looks like the issue with at FB side. Do I need to change some settings at FB page or something like that?